# Jquery AJAX from GET to POST

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following GET-request:

```
$('#Types').on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../Dashboard/DisplayTiles?type=' + $('#Types').val() + "&category=" + $('#Categories').val(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#loading').show();
            $('#search').val("");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#main').html(data);
            $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

How do i make this POST? I have tried googling it without a clear result... I want to specify the method as post and put the same data into the request as before (data in url).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `method` property to `'POST'` and provide an object with your data in to `data` property. Also remove the query string from the url provided

```
$.ajax({
    // Remove query string
    url: '../Dashboard/DisplayTiles',
    // Set method to 'POST'
    method: 'POST',
    // Provide the data object
    data: { 
       type: $('#Types').val(),
       category: $('#Categories').val()
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#loading').show();
        $('#search').val("");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#main').html(data);
        $('#loading').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use method parameter of ajax like:

```
$.ajax({
    url         : 'ajax_process.php',
    method      : 'post',
    data        :
    {

    },
    success     : function(response)
    {

    });
```

Comment: How do i write the data? like type =  $('#Types').val()

Answer (score 0):

Use `type: 'POST'` in `$.ajax()`.

Comment: use comments for such a short replies, it's not a full-fledged answer with the explanation on the original question.

Comment: I don't agree. Apart from its length, this answer provides an alternative solution to the ask question. You could ask me to develop, give source or you could tell me that I'm wrong and explain why

Comment: @mathiasbe, I'd not be that self-confident, I just tried to help you out, as your post was a candidate for deletion reported by someone. Other than that, you answer is incorrect so get the down-vote from me. If you'd be not that lazy - you'd check, that in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) `ajax()` **doesn't have `type`** parameter, it has **`method`** which may accept HTTP method to use for the request (e.g. "POST", "GET", "PUT")... good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.